# For single barrier options, why is a plot of gamma so scattered compared to other greeks?

Tags: black-scholes, gamma, barrier

Is this to be expected or is there something wrong with the model?

I am getting scattered gamma plots for all types of barriers like U&O, D&I, etc
[image]

---

However a basic vanilla options has a smooth gamma plot.
[image]

Comment: How are you defining and calculating your gamma?

Comment: Can you add a bit more about which kind of barrier you're looking at?

Comment: Using Huag vba code.  The barrier was standard barrier up and out call.  gamma is scattered for u&o, d&o.

Comment: What is huag vba code? Could you please be more specific, especially with your gamma calculations?

Comment: I think OP means code from Espen Haug's book.

Comment: I don’t think it’s gamma itself, it’s likely to be a limit in your discretization scheme, which makes second order derivatives less precise

Answer (score 4):

Your gamma seems to be "quantized" like if your calculation happens to be at the machine limit in term of precision. Maybe you aren't using a "dS" large enough if you compute derivatives using a finite difference approach.

Try increase the step for your numerical calculation.

Comment: I second that. Look at the formulas for Greeks, it's likely bump and reprice and the same problem as shown in [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/66170/54838).

Answer (score 0):

it had to do with dS being too small. After changing dS from .0001 to .01 the scattered plots went away

Comment: Thx for the update but your answer looks like confirmation of @PC1's answer rather than a separate answer.

Comment: it was a coincidence.  if you look at the timestamps in made my post before pc1 but its good to know we found the same solution

Comment: It might still have been a coincidence of course if you did not see it, but you are wrong about your answer being earlier than @PC1’s; that answer has been posted in November 2021 while yours has been posted in December 2021.