Definition of Theta in presence of time varying volatility
I’m wondering what is the right or standard way to think/define Theta decay with time varying volatility such as the ones observed in the market.
One way could be to fix implied vol and use vol*sqrt(time to expiry) where appropriate. Therefore time decomposes from volatility. This appears the simplest however theta decay wouldn’t capture effects like volatility crushing. In this case it seems that one has to capture that risk through Vega. Perhaps that would be closest to A BS formula.
The other would be to account for the changing vol between expiries. Accounting for that in theta would be somewhat related to removing from the total variance what the market sort of implies for the immediate variance. This could incorporate volatility crushing in theta directly.
More generally it seems that defining Greeks in a real scenario becomes unclear. Do practitioners tend to use one definition of Greeks or do they resort to custom models.

Greeks are always all else equal. See https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/74749/54838 for FD, which works in any model.

Assuming vanilla options. Greeks become more unclear with exotics, see https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/69775/54838.

There are indeed (at least) two ways to compute theta, which is defined as a 1 day time bump:

Fixed expiry, where the implied vol of the option is kept constant: this is Black-Scholes theta;
Fixed tenor, where the vol surface is rolled forward by 1 day, and so the implied vol of the option is effectively rolled down by one day: this captures your second point.

Note that these definitions work for any product, not just vanilla options.
Regarding Greeks in general, it's really up to the practitioner. There are standard definitions of Greeks, but then you shouldn't be constrained by definitions. They are tools, and practitioners should master their tools!
