# Delta on dividend paying equity index

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, delta

we calculate the delta as change in NPV for 1% change in spot * 100.  Would bumping up the forward price by same 1% produce the same results?  I'm assuming F = S *exp(... ) or it's too simplifying assuming dividends?

Comment: Do you mean computing delta as finite difference? If so, as long as you have $F \neq S$, bumping F by 1% will not be identical to bumping S by 1 %. Side remark, you wouldn't usually just bump up but use something like [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/66170/54838).

Comment: yes, using central difference per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Basic_types) , but can you please elaborate on  _"as long as you have F≠S
, bumping F by 1% will not be identical to bumping S by 1 %._?

Comment: Well, a 1% bump of a value of 100 isn't the same as a 1% bump of 99.5 for example.